# how to insert blank rows in excel without copying formulas using macros

Tags: excel, vba

Say if I select cell A2, and cell A2 has data validation in it and other cells in same row no.2 have vlookup and other formulas in it.

Now I want to insert a blank row below row no. 2 with no formulas being copied from row 2.

I should be able to give a fixed location of the cell in the macros below which I want to  insert the blank row

Till now i have been using this:

Range("A3").EntireRow.Insert

Comment: I do not believe you can avoid the formulae being copied down.  Why not clear the contents of the new row to remove them?

Comment: yeah I am already doing it the way that you have suggested, I was just wondering if there was some shortcut

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me:

```
Range("A3").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```